# How to copy part of a URL to a redirect path

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, fastly

I am trying to redirect a path e.g. `www.something.com/apple/pie` to `www.something.com/tickets/pie-details`

This is what I have tried but doesn't work:

```
if (req.url ~ "^/apple/.*") {
    set req.url = "^/tickets/.*-details";
    error 701 req.url;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58309227/how-to-add-redirect-exceptions-using-varnish , by the same user

Answer (score 0):

You either need to capture the matches from the regex, or if it is simple just replace using `regsub()`

However I have read that these are no longer bundled in core varnish so you might need a vmod. This one appears to be the one you need: https://gitlab.com/uplex/varnish/libvmod-re

Here are some docs on how this can be used: https://docs.fastly.com/en/guides/vcl-regular-expression-cheat-sheet#capturing-matches

Basically the `re` object lets you use the matched portion to then assemble the new url using string operations.

All of the above is speculative using my knowledge of vcl and regex, but I personally have not tried it.